# jQuery selector context

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, what does `, this` mean?

```javascript
var popup = $(popup, this).css('opacity', 0);
```

Answer (score 50):

The second argument in the selector is a context for search. `$(a,b)` is the same as `$(b).find(a)`.

More information can be found at *[jQuery(), section "jQuery( selector, [ context ] )"](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context)*.

Comment: what would be the difference between `$(a,b)` and `$(b a)` (look for descendants of 'b' that are 'a')?

Comment: That's a good start, but I wonder what the `this` in `var popup = $(popup, this)` is doing. That's an interesting construction. If I already have `this` in context, why not simply wrap it in`$()`?, Am I saying, "_If `this` isn't in a popup [then...]_"? That's kind of clever. It's (possibly?) a slightly more interesting question than this answer provides.