# Drupal8/9 jQuery select DOM element with context

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, drupal-8

In Drupal8/9 I can select elements in the context with jQuery like this two method:

`$('#dom-element', context)` or `$(context).find('#dom-element')`

When I print these two methods I get back the same DOM element, but when I try to compare these two kinds of select `$('#dom-element', context) === $(context).find('#dom-element')` is `FALSE` (both are object).

These select used in many places, tutorials, descriptions, but I don't know which one is better and why? Why do I need to use the one instead of the other? I can use both, but what's the benefits or disadvantages of the one or the other? What kind of select is faster than the other? Which one has better performance?

**Edit:**
*This answer will perfect to me:*
[jquery find versus context selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342282/jquery-find-versus-context-selection#answer-9046288)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery selector context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665057/jquery-selector-context)

Comment: And as the answer in duplicate say: _The second argument in the selector is a context for search. `$(a,b)` is the same as `$(b).find(a)`._. You can also see it in the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L92)

Comment: [Check this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equality-for-two-javascript-objects/) as to why === is not returning true